# Struts2: custom action mapper defined in Spring

Tags: spring, struts2

I have following situation:

- I use Struts2 as MVC cobtroller
- I use Spring as object factory
- I implemented custom action mapper, I have configured this as a bean in my spring configuration.

How can I tell Struts to use this bean as an action mapper?

I tried top set:

```
struts.mapper.class=beanName
```

in `struts.properties` but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have have following the struts.xml file ? This is required to tell Struts2 that objects will be created by Spring

```
<struts>
 <constant name="struts.objectFactory" value="org.apache.struts2.spring.StrutsSpringObjectFactory" />
    ... 
</struts>
```

OR

Add the following property in the struts.properties

```
struts.objectFactory = org.apache.struts2.spring.StrutsSpringObjectFactory
```

Comment: Yes I have this property set. But I cannot convince Struts2 to use bean created by Spring as action mapper. I was able to do this when we used webwork, now I try to migrate to Struts and cannot make this work.

Comment: Can you post your configuration files ( struts and spring )?

Comment: Turns out I had it all wrong. I added this property and struts2-spring-plugin-x.x.x and now it works fine.